# f is holomorphic on the unit disk, with $Re(f(z)) >0$ for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that $|f^\prime(0)| \leq 2Re (f(0))$.

I have no idea on how to proceed in this question. I cannot use Schwarz lemma since we have no information about $f$ at 0. I also do not understand how the property $Re(f(z)) >0$ relates to the question. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does that inequality mean? after all, $f'(0)$ might well be non-real, right?!

Comment: You *can* use the Schwarz Lemma, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/461310.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos edited

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1684925/42969.

Comment: wow, i would've never thought to do that. thanks!